# removeClass of imageelement in a tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I will remove on every images in the table witch have the class .rowUp a other class

```
$("#" + tableName + " tr").each(function () {
    $(this)
        .closest(" img.rowUp img.rowDown")
        .removeClass("imgDisplayNone");
});
```

But it doesnt remove the class.

The images are in the table in the row:

```
<tr class="OfferPosition trAvailableArticle trAvailableArticleBackground" id="2503">
    <td class="tdArticlePositionEdit">
        <img class="editPosition imgPointer" src="/images/edit.png">
    </td>
    <td class="tdArticlePositionRubbish">                                                                                                                     
        <img class="imgPointer rowUp imgDisplayNone" src="/images/arrow_up.png">
        <img class="imgPointer rowDown " src="/images/arrow_down.png">

    </td>
</tr>
```

the script doesn't remove the class in the image

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop for this. You can do it like:

```
$('table').find('img.rowUp').removeClass('imgDisplayNone');
```

OR

```
$("#" + tableName +  " tr").each(function () {
     $(this)
    .find(" img.rowUp, img.rowDown")
    .removeClass("imgDisplayNone");
});
```

Comment: It's better to keep original `$("#" + tableName + " tr")` or at least `$("#" + tableName)`. And, by the way, you forgot about `.rowDown`

Comment: @Regent Who said it is better to keep the original?? And please look at the question *** the class .rowUp a other class*** only `.rowUp` is mentioned.

Comment: Because there can be more than one table on the page. About classes - well, I really think (seeing previous OP's question) that it's required to delete both images

Comment: @Regent If that was it would have been mentioned in question. And assumptions are not good. Well there is no mention of OP's question as well but anyway relax :)

Comment: It actually mentioned in `.closest(" img.rowUp img.rowDown")`. Well, anyway, I vote for your answer, because it's the first and the correct one

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#" + tableName + " tr td").each(function()
            {
                $(this)
                    .find("img.rowUp")
                    .removeClass("imgDisplayNone" );
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#" + tableName ).find('img.rowUp,img.rowDown').removeClass( "imgDisplayNone" );
```